# Embedding $G$ into $G/N \times A$ for some small group $A$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $N \unlhd G$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.
I would like to embed $G$ in $(G/N) \times A$ for some small group $A$.
I require the embedding to map $g \in G$ to $(gN, a_g)$ for some $a_g \in A$.
What is the smallest $A$ I can take?

Comment: Universally, $A=G$.

Comment: Do you want the embedding to be a homomorphism?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always take *A* = *G*, and often you cannot do better. If *G* is cyclic of order 4 and *N* is the normal subgroup of index 2, then the smallest *A* that works is of course *G*, since *G*/*N* × *A* must at the very least have an element of order 4.

Another silly case:

- When *N* = 1, you can always take *A* = 1.
- When *N* = *G*, the minimal choice is *A* = *G*.

Consider the homomorphism φ from *G* to *G*/*N* × *A* given by *g* → ( *gN*, *f*(*g*) ).  Notice that *f* must be a homomorphism from *G* to *A*. What is the kernel of φ? It is just the intersection of the kernel of *f* with N.  Hence we take *A* to be minimal amongst all *G*/*M* where *M* ∩ *N* = 1.

For instance, if *G* is a *p*-group with a cyclic center and *N* ≠ 1, then *A* = *G* is minimal.  If *G* is dihedral of order 2*p* and *N* ≠ 1, then *A* = *G* is minimal.  If *G* is dihedral of order 2*pq* and *N* has order *p*, then one can take *A* to be dihedral of order 2*p*, that is *M* has order *q*.  Here *p* ≠ *q* are distinct odd primes.

In particular, if *N* contains the socle of *G*, then *A* = *G* is minimal. The converse also holds, since otherwise *M* being a minimal normal subgroup not contained in *N* will work for *A* = *G*/*M*.